Can anyone tell what's wrong with this script that should process my microphone input?
I'm trying to make an app that records my mike's audio on 1 thread, and creates 5 second chunks.  It then places each of those chunks into a queue, that sends it to a second thread to transcribe the audio to text, then adding the text to a second queue.  Finally, it goes to a third thread, which will perform a variety of opperations on the string.  For now, it just prints it for debug purposes.
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import threading
import queue
import time
from faster_whisper import WhisperModel 
audio_model = WhisperModel(model_path)  # Initialize faster_whisper model
fs = 44100  # Sampling rate
audio_q = queue.Queue()  # Queue to communicate raw audio data between threads
text_q = queue.Queue()  # Queue to communicate transcribed text between threads
short_chunk_duration = 0.1  # Short chunk duration in seconds (e.g., 100ms)
long_chunk_duration = 5  # Desired chunk duration in seconds (5 seconds)


# --- Thread Functions ---
def record_audio():
    """Continuously records audio and adds 5-second chunks to the queue."""

    accumulated_buffer = []

    def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
        nonlocal accumulated_buffer
        if status:
            print(status)

        accumulated_buffer.append(indata.copy())

        # Check if we have accumulated enough data for a 5-second chunk
        if (
            len(accumulated_buffer) * int(short_chunk_duration * fs)
            >= long_chunk_duration * fs
        ):
            # Concatenate the accumulated chunks into one array
            long_chunk = np.concatenate(accumulated_buffer)
            audio_q.put(long_chunk)  # Add the 5-second chunk to the queue
            accumulated_buffer = []  # Reset the buffer

    with sd.InputStream(samplerate=fs, channels=1, callback=callback):
        while True:
            sd.sleep(int(short_chunk_duration * 1000))


def transcribe_audio():
    """Takes audio from the queue, transcribes it, and puts text in the queue."""

    while True:
        audio_data = audio_q.get()
        audio_array = np.frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=np.float32)

        # Confirming audio_array fits the requirements of faster_whisper
        if audio_array.ndim == 1:
            audio_array = np.expand_dims(audio_array, axis=0)

        # Transcribe with faster_whisper
        segments, _ = audio_model.transcribe(audio_array)

        # The result structure is different; let's collect all transcriptions
        text = ""
        for segment in segments:
            text += segment.text

        print(f"Transcribed: {text}")

        audio_q.task_done()
        text_q.put(text)  # Put transcribed text into the queue


def process_text():
    pass
# --- Start Threads ---
if __name__ == "__main__":
    recording_thread = threading.Thread(target=record_audio)
    transcribing_thread = threading.Thread(target=transcribe_audio)
    processing_thread = threading.Thread(target=process_text)

    recording_thread.daemon = True
    transcribing_thread.daemon = True
    processing_thread.daemon = True

    recording_thread.start()
    transcribing_thread.start()
    processing_thread.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Terminating threads...")

It should transcribe my microphone in 5 second chunks, then print it to the console, however, it's giving me an error saying that it's trying to alocate 960 GB of ram for numpy.  I haven't used numpy much, so I'd guess it's something to do with the logic that expands the audio object into an array.

Please edit your question to include the complete error report starting with the word traceback. You can surround the report with 3 before and 3 after to properly format the output.
